# calling angular 2 route from another component to load the page in another component?

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 2 app and I have navigation component and I have another component where I have  . I am trying to access the route from one navigation and get the page loaded to the other component.

IF anyone knows how the routing works between components then please let me know,

Thanks

Comment: A bit more detail and some sample code will help. The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Parent', 'Child']">Navigate somewhere</a>
```

but hard to tell without more information.